# error function decode(bytea unknown) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

when I run this query in Postgres, on a `bytea` column:

```
SELECT decode(column_name, 'escape') FROM table_name;
```

I get this failure:
`error function decode(bytea unknown) does not exist`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems I got it flipped, you can use the `decode` method on inserts, ex:

```
 insert into table_name values (decode(E'abc123\\000456', 'escape'));
```

but not use it on selects, should be this instead

```
SELECT encode(column_name, 'escape') FROM table_name;
```